# How to Edit Fields in MainForm Linked to SubForm

Tags: sql, vba, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a handful of fields linked to a subform (in datasheet view) on my mainform and I would like to be able to edit the data in the table from the fields since the subform is very wide and hard to see all of it. The subform is pulling data through a query to put multiple tables together and I think that's what's preventing me from editing the data from the fields based on what I've seen. The SQL statement that links the fields to the subform is like the following for several fields:`=[SubformX].[Form]![Data]` I was wondering if some kind of VBA/Query would be able to directly populate the fields based on the subform selection and still allow it to be edited or if there is a simple fix for this problem.

Comment: The query must be editable in order to be able to edit it.  Which sounds redundant, but a lot of people don't seem to understand that.  Run the query without the form, and if it says, "The recordset is not updateable" then you have your problem right there.  Without seeing the data, it's difficult to say why your recordset isn't updateable.  If it's linked to SQL Server, make sure your tables all have indexes or the data will not be updateable.  You can also check your Relationships setup and make sure the tables are linked properly.

Comment: The query runs fine, and I can still edit the data in the subform it's based on so I would assume the data is updatable. As for linking, I have 3 simple one to many links between 3 different tables that work properly so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: So you have a subform that you can't update, that's fed by a query that you can update?

Comment: The query and the subform can both be updated but the fields on the subform's parent form that are linked to the subform are not updatable.

Comment: Ahhh...  Yes, because they're just reference controls.  You would have to write some code to open the record and write the values to the table.  To the best of my knowledge you can't have a control (textbox) that references another control (datagrid) that can update that control.  Do you really need to have the data in 2 different places simultaneously?

Comment: I guess that makes sense that it wouldn't be able to access the information through two controls. And yeah, the people I'm making it for really want it to be like that (I know it's silly but that's not my call).

Comment: As the developer, you're going to have to make that call.  Due to record-locking issues, you can't edit the same recordset from 2 different locations when both locations have the same record open.

Comment: So there isn't a workaround for it then?

Comment: You can create a recordset clone, or write it all to a temp table or something, but as a programmer you need to set expectations on your deliverable.  And doing either of those is not a great idea.

Comment: From my experience, The sub form query should have the primary key included in the query  (not necessarily displayed).

Answer (score 0):

Due to natural limitations on updating data from a form, it seems this approach is not workable without using VBA to stage the update and display.  Refer to the comments above for some detail.